# In business model, how can I classify the tasks based on from where materials are utilised?

Tags: project-management-style

I want to classify a task based on whether – 
1) materials are issued by the department,
2) materials are not required,
3) materials are procured by contractors themselves.

What different terms are used in business for these kind of model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the category field any of the following:

1. acquisition method
2. materials supplier (or supplied by)
3. materials responsible
4. required materials

And in MS Project you can,

1. create a custom field,
2. Or use a text field.